# How to check if raw_input is float and contains only one decimal point?

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, raw-input

Code:

```
x=raw_input("Enter: ")
if x.isfloat():
   print x
else:
   print "error"
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/DLLs/delete", line 4, in <module>
    if not x.isNumber():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isNumber'
```

Comment: Your error message doesn't correspond to the code you claim to be running. `isfloat` and `isNumber` aren't valid [string methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). Why not write your own `is_float` function?

Comment: Don't write your code in the `C:\Python27` directory, or any subdirectory under it.

Comment: Do you mean how to check that `x` is a float and contains only one *number after* the decimal point? E.g. `1.2` is OK but `1.23` isn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use `try` and find out?

```
x = raw_input("Enter: ")
try:
    x = float(x)
except ValueError:
    print "error"
else:
    print x
```

This ["easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp) style is a common Python idiom.

---

If you *do* mean checking for numbers with only one digit after the decimal place, you can adapt this slightly:

```
try:
    if len(x.split(".", 1)[1]) == 1:
        x = float(x)
    else:
        print "error" # too many d.p.
except (IndexError, ValueError):
    print "error" # no '.' or not a float
else:
    print x
```

Here the `IndexError` would catch `x` not containing any `'.'`s and the `ValueError` catches `x` not being interpretable as a `float`. In general, you may want to split these checks out to report a more useful error to the user (e.g. `"Error: couldn't convert '{0}' to float.".format(x)`) or even raise an actual `Exception`.

Comment: Hey, @jonrsharpe. I'm sure you ment x.split('.', 1)